# Fade multiple elements one after the other

Tags: jquery, fadein

Is there any possible solution, to **fadeIn(500)** multiple list elements one after the other?

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 17):

You could do a recursive function that stops when there's no LI left like this:

```
function fadeLI(elem) { 
  elem.fadeIn(500, function() { fadeLI($(this).next()); }); 
}                            
fadeLI($("#list li:first")​);​
```

[Check it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/)

Answer (score 0):

You want a recursive function to check if there is another li element, and fade it in if so...

```
function fadeInNext(el){
  if(el.next('li')){
    el.next('li').fadeIn(500,fadeInNext)
  }
}
$('...').fadeIn( 500, fadeInNext )
```

Comment: This won't work..you're not passing the next element into `fadeInNext`, in either case in jQuery the `if(el.next('li'))` isn't needed...if it doesn't find anything matching the selector, it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this.. add each child into a array and
make a function which see's if the length of the array is greater then 0,
then it get's the first item of the Array and fadeToggle's the child which in turn toggle's a function within the fadeToggle and it jumps to the next child element.. for more information about shift() check out http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_shift.asp

```
var toggleList = [];
$("#container").children().each(function() {
toggleList.push(this);
});

function fadeToggleList(toggleList) {
if (toggleList.length > 0) {
    var currentChild = toggleList.shift();
    $(currentChild).fadeToggle(50, function() {
        fadeToggleList(toggleList);
    });
}
}
fadeToggleList(toggleList);
```

Comment: this is not the best but at least it functions.