# Fade in elements one by one, then fade them all out and start over

Tags: jquery, jquery-events, fadein, fadeout

I need to fade in several list elements, then fade them all out and start over. I've got the code I found here: http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/, which was pointed out here: [Fade multiple elements one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546467/jquery-fade-multiple-elements-one-after-the-other). However, I need to run this code recursively (i.e. - fade out all elements, then call the function again and start over).

Could someone share the right code for this, please?

Comment: Probably it was only that your brain hiccuped, but just to be sure: You wouldn't want to do it recursively. Iteration is the thing you'll use, right?

Comment: 'Brain hiccup' sounds about right... it's been a 12 hour work day, and I don't see the end of it as of yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update to jQuery 1.4.4 or later, you can use the `fadeToggle` method.

If you select all the elements that you want to fade, and send in the index of the next element to show/hide, you can easily loop and restart:

http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/48/

```
function fadeLI(elem, idx) {
    elem.eq(idx).fadeToggle(500, function() {
        fadeLI(elem, (idx + 1) % elem.length);
    });
}

fadeLI($("#list li"), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there *is* a next element; if not, you're at the end of the list; then fade everything out and run with the first element.

Comment: Yes, I understand the logic, but I need some help with the correct code for this (trying to be careful with recursive functions here).

Answer (score 0):

Change the fadeLI to as below:

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mqthK/45/

```
function fadeLI(elem, show) {
        if(elem.length == 0){
            fadeLI($("#list li:first"));
        }
        if(elem.is(":visible")){
        elem.fadeOut(500, function() {
                    fadeLI($(this).next());
            });
        }
        else{
            elem.fadeIn(500, function() {
                    fadeLI($(this).next());
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like what I needed. However, on your working example the first list element keeps flickering when the elements are fading out. Why is that?

Comment: It is because you are hiding the elements hence there are assigned a style attribute of display: none hence the elements beneath the current elements are bumped up in the viewport. If you want to avoid the flickering then you have to toggle the visibility attribute.